# TTrackBar.SelStart/SelEnd markers not drawn when VCL styles are enabled

Tags: delphi, themes, trackbar

SelStart/SelEnd "markers" of TTrackBar are not drawn when VCL styles are enabled. I tried with multiple themes.

There is nothing I can do from the theme editor. And the TrackBar does not have a Paint method to override.
What would be the best way to fix that? Or do I miss something obvious (a way to enable the painting of those markers)?

Comment: I'm sure this differs as per Delphi/Windows version/combination - which of those affect you?

Comment: @AmigoJack - Hi. Can you explain? Why it would be so different on Win7 vs Win10 (for example). Also, as any other program, the solution should work on as many Windows OSs as possible. I mean, this is the way the VCL works now. Right? :)

Comment: Do you mean the windows theme, or do you mean VCL styles?

Comment: VCL styles (but they also call them themes).

Comment: The Delphi version matters. VCL styles has been a giant bug factory. Each delphi release fixes a bunch of bugs and introduces new ones.

Comment: Ha ha... like the bug I am trying to fix now? One day, they will get there. Same for the FMX. It is getting closer and closer to be (barely) usable :)

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience: You see, I'm not alone in disliking VCL styles! :)